# Why can't a point charge between two oppositely charged particles be located off the axis going through them?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law

[image: Screenshot of Question Regarding Two Oppositely Charged Particles]

I understand the answer to part (a), but I don't understand why the answer to (b) is that there's no position off the x-axis where "q3" will be in equilibrium.

[image: Diagram of Two Possible Positions for Q3]

So, I understand why it can't be between the particles or the right of particle 2, but is there not some point to left of q1 (such as position A) where q3 will have net zero electrostatic force acting on it (ignoring my inaccurate drawing)?

Considering, if (for example) q3 has a positive charge, then the force on it from q1 would be up and to the left and the force on it from q3 would be down and to the right, why can't the net force be zero?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two non-zero forces acting on it. So the only way for the net force to be zero is for the two forces to be equal and opposite. Off of the axis it is not possible for the forces to be opposite, they will always point along different lines.

For example, assume a positive test charge off the axis, the force will be towards charge 2 and away from charge 1. The angle between the forces will be equal to 180 deg minus the angle formed in a triangle with the three corners at the three charges. That will always be less than 180 degrees since the angle will never be zero.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm just wondering there's an intuitive or geometric explanation for this. My question is, I guess, why can't they be on the same line, exactly? Sorry if I'm being dense.

Comment: Sure, I added a paragraph explaining the geometry

Comment: Thank you! I think I finally understand :)